# Having trouble with account creation using HTML, node.js, express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hi I'm trying to create a simple HTML interface where users can create an account and log in. I'm struggling with getting the account creation to work, let alone logging in.

This is my accountCreate.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create Account</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="accountCreatePage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="Scrumbucks.png" alt="logo" width="150px" height="150px">
        <h1 class="center">Create an Account</h1>
    </header>
    <form id="accountCreateForm" class="account-create" action="/createUser" method="post">
        <h2>Account Creation</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
    </form>
    <div class="return-button">
        <a href="login.html"><button>Return to Login</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my server.js that supposedly connects successfully to my database. I removed database specs for privacy reasons but when I run "npm start" in my terminal I get the messages "DB connected successfully" and "Server is running on port xxxx" :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const mysql = require("mysql");

const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host: "---.---.-.--",
  user: "--------------",
  password: "----------"
  database: "-----------",
  port: "----"
});

db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) throw (err);
  console.log("DB connection successful: " + connection.threadId);
});

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
app.use(express.json()); 

// CREATE USER
app.post("/createUser", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Route accessed"); 

  const { firstName, lastName, email, username, password } = req.body;

  if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "All fields are required" });
  }

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

  const sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE username = ?";
  const search_query = mysql.format(sqlSearch, [username]);

  const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO userInfo (firstName, lastName, email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  const insert_values = [firstName, lastName, email, username, hashedPassword];
  const insert_query = mysql.format(sqlInsert, insert_values);

  db.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error connecting to the database: " + err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Database connection error" });
    }

    connection.query(search_query, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        connection.release();
        console.error("Error searching for existing user: " + err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Database query error" });
      }

      if (results.length > 0) {
        connection.release();
        return res.status(409).json({ error: "User already exists" });
      }

      connection.query(insert_query, (err, results) => {
        connection.release();

        if (err) {
          console.error("Error inserting new user: " + err);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: "Database query error" });
        }

        console.log("New user created with ID: " + results.insertId);
        return res.status(201).json({ message: "User created successfully" });
      });
    });
  });
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I believe the error is with the /createUser pathway. Because everytime I run this code I get redirected to the /createUser path on my laptop (which causes a file not found error) where I just want it to run the /createUser route I defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: "Because everytime I run this code I get redirected to the /createUser path on my laptop" — Do you mean your browser navigates to `file:///createUser`? And not `http://localhost:3000/createUser`?

Comment: no i get redirected here: http://localhost:3000/createUser. I just want all the information in my form fields to be stored in my database so i can use them later for logging in. Ideally when I press the submit button i am redirected to my success.html page and all the info is saved in my db. I know the db is not being accessed because not a single on of the console log statements show up when I inspect the page on my browser.